# To run .bat file contains two operation simultaneously standalone war file and open chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, batch-file

HI in my case I want to run standalone war spring boot application java -jar test_xxxxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Once the server is UP, need to run chrome browser pointing the standalone war having UI code index page.

This is my bat file

```
java -jar test_xxxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
SLEEP 10

START chrome.exe "http://localhost:8080"
```

This cause only server is up but chrome browser is not starting. Need to run both with certain time interval

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` will open Chrome and will wait until it is closed before moving to the next command. The next command, `SLEEP 10`, is not valid, there's no such command by default in Windows, you should instead use the `Timeout` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chrome is getting started prematurely with this line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

First you `cd` directory and then start chrome with the URL parameter

```
java -jar test_xxxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
SLEEP 10

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
START chrome.exe "http://localhost:8080"
```